# C# - Reading Text Files(System IO)

Tags: c#, text-files

I would like to consecutively read from a text file that is generated by my program. The problem is that after parsing the file for the first time, my program reads the last line of the file before it can begin re-parsing, which causes it to accumulates unwanted data.

---

[3 photos: first is creating tournament and showing points, second is showing text file and the third is showing that TeamA got more 3 points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNxoG.jpg)

```
   StreamReader = new StreamReader("Torneios.txt");

   torneios = 0;
   while (!rd.EndOfStream)
   {
       string line = rd.ReadLine();
       if (line == "Tournament") 
       { 
           torneios++;
       } 
       else 
       {
           string[] arr = line.Split('-');
           equipaAA = arr[0];
           equipaBB = arr[1];
           res = Convert.ToChar(arr[2]); 
       }
   }
   rd.Close();
```

That is what I'm using at the moment.

Comment: Please use proper punctuation and grammar while asking questions and be specific about the problem.

Comment: Please read the [help] page and edit your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid mistakes like these, I highly recommend using `File.ReadAllText` or `File.ReadAllLines` unless you are using large files (in which case they are not good choices), here is an example of an implementation of such:

```
string result = File.ReadAllText("textfilename.txt");
```

Regarding your particular code, an example using `File.ReadAllLines` which achieves this is:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("textfilename.txt");
for(int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
{
  string line = lines[i];
  //Do whatever you want here
}
```

Just to make it clear, this is not a good idea if the files you intend to read from are large (such as binary files).

Comment: While those are indeed good options for small files, if you have to read huge files those are definitively not the way to go.

Comment: @Prix Agreed, will edit that into the answer just to make it clear.